# Why does ExecutorCompletionService does not use threads from ExecutorService pool

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

For some reason the `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService` is not using thread(s) from `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` thread pool. This affects a "blocking" execution to `ExecutorCompletionService.submit()` method call. Please consider the following code:

```
package completionservicedemo1;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class CompletionServiceDemo1 {

    static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new ThreadFactory() {

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.setName("Executor-Thread");
            try {
                System.out.println("Thread going to sleep: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                thread.sleep(5000L);
                System.out.println("Thread awakened: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("InteruptedException: "+ex);
            }
            return thread;
        }
    });

    static final ExecutorCompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
    static byte val=1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("App start time: "+ new Date());

        completionService.submit(()->"String"+ ++val);
        System.out.println("All tasks submitted at: "+ new Date());

    }    
}
```

And the output:

App start time: Tue Jan 05 00:20:27 IST 2016

Thread going to sleep: main

Thread awakened: main

All tasks submitted at: Tue Jan 05 00:20:32 IST 2016

It is quite clear that ExecutorCompletionStage is not using thread from ExecutorService pool and because of this `completionService.submit(()->"String"+ ++val);` is responds after a delay of 5s.

Ideally submit() method should submit the passed Callable instance task to the ExecutorService pool for concurrent execution. But that is apparently not happening either as the name of the Thread in the output reveals.

Can somebody please explain whats happening here? Why isn't the Callable being computed on ExecutorService Thread pool concurrently? Why is completionService.submit() blocking (for 5s)?

Comment: What do you think a `ThreadFactory` and its `newThread` method do?

Comment: What do you think `completionService.submit(()->"String"+ ++val);` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for your comments.

ThreadFactory's newMethod() is a means of providing custom Thread instances to the ExecutorService Pool rather than the runtime create on its own.

completionService.submit() is a means of submitting tasks modelled as Callables to the ExecutorCompletionService which inturn would compute the Callable on any thread from the ExecutorService thread pool. This is what I understand but willing to be enlightened :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does `ExecutorCompletionService` does not use threads from `ExecutorService` pool?

It does. See end of answer.

The [javadoc of `newFixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory-) states

> using the provided `ThreadFactory` to create new threads when needed

In other words, the returned `ExecutorService`'s threads are created with `newThread` lazily, on demand.

When you submit a task

```
completionService.submit(()->"String"+ ++val);
```

there are no `Thread` instances available to accept the task. The `ExecutorService` will therefore create a new thread using `newThread`. It does this in the calling thread, `main`. Since your `newThread` is implemented to sleep for 5 seconds, that's exactly what it does. Once the `sleep` completes, `newThread` will return the `Thread` instance, which the `ExecutorService` will start and execute the submitted

```
()->"String"+ ++val
```

---

Note that your task only concatenates a `String` and an `int` value and returns the result.

Change it to

```
Future<String> future = completionService.submit(() -> "String" + ++val + " Thread " + Thread.currentThread());
System.out.println("All tasks submitted at: " + new Date());
System.out.println("Future returned: " + future.get());
```

calling `get` on the returned `Future` to wait for it to complete and to see something useful.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @Sotirios Delimanolis' reply, I was able to fix my problem and understand the issue. I had misplaced the search for worker thread name that would execute Callable inside `ThreadFactory.newThread()` instead of the `Callable.call()` method. After fixing this case, everything is coherent:

```
package completionservicedemo1;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class CompletionServiceDemo1 {

    static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new ThreadFactory() {

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.setName("Executor-Thread");
            try {
                System.out.println("Thread going to sleep: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                thread.sleep(1000L);
                System.out.println("Thread awakened: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("InteruptedException: "+ex);
            }
            return thread;
        }
    });

    static final ExecutorCompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
    static byte val=1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("App start time: "+ new Date());

        completionService.submit(()->{
            System.out.println("Thread executing the callable: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+new Date());
            Thread.sleep(10000L);
            System.out.println("Worker Thread came out of sleep: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+new Date());
            return "String"+ ++val;
        });
        System.out.println("All tasks submitted at: "+ new Date());

        System.out.println("main thread taking completed future at: "+new Date());

        //following would block on the BlockingQue as there is a 10s delay
        Future<String> resultingFuture = completionService.take(); 

        //following would not block since only completed Futures are placed on the BlockingQue (by QueueingFuture)
            System.out.println("result: "+resultingFuture.get()); 

        System.out.println("main thread got completed future result at: "+new Date());

    }    
}
```

Output:

App start time: Tue Jan 05 08:00:06 IST 2016

Thread going to sleep: main

Thread awakened: main

All tasks submitted at: Tue Jan 05 08:00:07 IST 2016

main thread taking completed future at: Tue Jan 05 08:00:07 IST 2016

Thread executing the callable: Executor-Thread Tue Jan 05 08:00:07 IST 2016

Worker Thread came out of sleep: Executor-Thread Tue Jan 05 08:00:17 IST 2016

result: String2

main thread got completed future result at: Tue Jan 05 08:00:17 IST 2016